# Can you hide the Solvers in an OpenMDAO N2 Diagram

Tags: openmdao

I'm embedding a lot of N2 Diagrams in my documentation and things fit much better without the solvers being displayed and for some simple systems, it's not excessively important. Is there any way to optionally hide those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of OpenMDAO V3.4 there is no button to hide them. There is an open issue to add that button though https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/issues/1363

In the short term, since you are embedding it you can do a bit of CSS hacking to make it work.

If you add the following the CSS:

```
#solver_tree {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

then it will hide the solver tree for you.